# The term 'jmeter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: jmeter

The term 'jmeter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

At line:1 char:1

- jmeter -n -t D:\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-
  2.13\bin\zzz\zzz ...
- ~~~~~~

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (jmeter:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: I am trying to execute this on Windows Server 2012 R2 .. It is working fine on Windows 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use 'cmd' instead of the Powershell console. Also may sure that you have Jmeter(folder installation)\bin in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: i have 1 more question :)

Comment: I am trying to execute same thing using jenkins.. with EXECUTE COMMAND  
'jmeter -n -t D:\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\DevOPSScenarios\DevOps_Login-Copy.jmx -l D:\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\DevOPSScenarios\Result\rrrrr.jtl
'But getting an build Error :Building in workspace D:\Jenkins\workspace\US2.9_JMeter
[US2.9_JMeter] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson12135.bat
D:\Jenkins\workspace\US2.9_JMeter>jmeter -n -t D:\apache-jmeter-

Comment: 2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\zzz\zzz.jmx -l D:\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\zzz\Result\rrrrr.jtl 
'jmeter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: See this page, may can help you: http://antagonisticpleiotropy.blogspot.be/2012/08/running-jenkins-in-windows-with-regular.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows 10 and using Windows PowerShell make sure you are inside JMeter's bin folder and start your command with .\jmeter instead of only jmeter.

```
.\jmeter -n -t D:\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter- 2.13\bin\zzz\zzz ...
```